# TypeScript - mysql - socket.io re-emitting after failed login attempted

Tags: mysql, typescript, socket.io

I am having this issue where after I fail to sign in and then successfully sign into my game it will create a game instance for every time I failed to login. This also happens on failed sign up attempts.

I loved to give you guys more code for context but stack overflow would then want me to give more detail and I'm not sure what else to say. I'll just link my repo.

One failed attempt: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLjeJ.png)

Two game instances: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2DdR.png)

My repo: [elevaidusTS](https://github.com/RobertHolstein/ElevaidusTS)

**SERVER**

```
        socket.on('signIn', (signInInfo: any) => {
            let sql = 'SELECT * FROM player WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
            var query = this.db.query(sql, [signInInfo.username,signInInfo.password], (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    socket.emit('errorFromBackend', err.code);                        
                }else if(res.length === 0){
                    socket.emit('errorFromBackend', 'username and or password was incorrect');                 
                }else{
                    console.log(`\n\n===============>\t Player logging in\n`)
                    console.log(`===============>\t username: ${signInInfo.username}\n`)
                    console.log(`===============>\t password: ${signInInfo.password}\n`)
                    this.CreatePlayer(socket, { player: res[0], isNew: false });
                }
            })
        })
```

**CLIENT**

```
   public SignIn(): void {
    this.socket.emit('signIn', {username: signInUsername.value, password: signInPassword.value })
    this.socket.on('signedIn', (playerInfo: any) => {
      this.CreateGame(playerInfo);
    })
    this.socket.on('errorFromBackend', (err: string) => {
      alert(err);
    })
  }

  public SignUp(): void {
    this.socket.emit('signUp', {username: signInUsername.value, password: signInPassword.value })
    this.socket.on('signedUp', (playerInfo: any) => {
      this.CreateGame(playerInfo)
    })
    this.socket.on('errorFromBackend', (err: string) => {
      alert(err);
    })
  }
```

Comment: I don't know enough about Sockets.io to assist with this, but I've removed the Phaser tag as it doesn't seem specific to that framework. For someone else, it appears that `this.CreateGame(playerInfo)` is getting twice, which is adding the second game instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was putting my listener inside the same function as the emitter. When I pressed on the signup/signin button a new instance my listener would be created so when the listener would get hit every instance of the listener would do the work.

[helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720096/socket-io-sending-multiple-message-for-a-single-request)